# UIMA AS (Asynchronous Scaleout) Tutorial?

Tags: uima

Is anyone privy to a tutorial on UIMA Asynchronous Scaleout?  I've found one for distributed pipelines, generally, but not the asynchronous stuff.

Thanks

Comment: http://uima.apache.org/doc-uimaas-what.html

Comment: Simon O'Doherty, thank you for your attempt at constructive feedback.

Comment: Maybe you should detail what you have looked at, to give a better context to the level of your question. There is a 50 page manual on AS at that link.

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom of the [Getting Started: Apache UIMA Asynchronous Scaleout](http://uima.apache.org/doc-uimaas-what.html) page, you find the following mention

> See the README file in the top level directory for instructions on deploying and testing standard UIMA example annotators as UIMA AS services.

The README file contains various information for Installation and Setup, and examples for Starting the ActiveMQ Broker,  Deploying an Analysis Engine as a UIMA AS Asynchronous Service, Calling a UIMA AS Asynchronous Service, Migration from CPM to UIMA-AS...

It is present in the top level directory of the binary/source version.

A direct link to this [README file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/uima-as/trunk/README).